# Limit number of documents in a partition for cosmosdb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmosdb collection with each partition containing a set of documents.I would like to maintain the collection such that a logical partition('id' in this case) does not go over the limit of 5 documents. In the sample below, when a sixth entry(say for 8/11/2020) is added, I want to delete the document created on 7/13/2020 since that was updated the earliest.
Basically, I want to make sure for item with id 12345, there are only 5 latest entries and no more. This is to reduce the data in the db and thus avoid querying more data than what's needed.

```
{
"id": 12345,
"lastUpdated":  8/10/2020
},
{
"id": 12345,
"lastUpdated":  8/3/2020
},
{
"id": 12345,
"lastUpdated":  7/27/2020
},
{
"id": 12345,
"lastUpdated":  7/20/2020
},
{
"id": 12345,
"lastUpdated":  7/13/2020
}
```

I could do something like this:

1. Get all documents for id 12345
2. If count of documents is >=5, get the last document (with instance 5) and delete it.
3. Insert new document

However, that is a running 3 queries to insert a single document.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You're right, in that you'd have to maintain your own list of items to delete. You could perform this action in a stored proc (since sp's are partition-scoped), but you'd still have the multiple operations + related RU cost per operation. That said: I don't understand the need to limit number of items in a partition. Also, I'm assuming you're referring to *logical* partitions, correct? (since there's no way to control physical partitions without resorting to large amounts of data or artificially increasing RU/sec). Please edit your question to contain more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response! By limiting number of items in partition, I meant for a particular id, I only want to maintain 6 items to minimize the amount of data stored. Yes, I am referring to logical partitions (/id) in this case. Is there a way I can leverage TTL somehow?

Comment: Assuming it's just a matter of cleanup to limit growth, seems like a periodic maintenance job run using Azure Function or otherwise would be the simplest and avoid impacting the writes.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OFFSET 1 LIMIT 5` to get 5 latest entries.  For more details, you can read offical document about [OFFSET LIMIT clause in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-offset-limit).

You can get the count(assume 100) of data and set `ttl`, or delete directly. We can query like below.

```
SELECT f.id, f.lastUpdated FROM yourcosmosdb f ORDER BY f.lastUpdated OFFSET 6 LIMIT 100
```

**Foreach**

```
List<Task> concurrentDeleteTasks = new List<Task>();
while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    FeedResponse<response> res = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
    foreach (var item in res)
    {                        
        concurrentDeleteTasks.Add(container.DeleteItemAsync<response>(item.id, new PartitionKey(item.deviceid)));
    }
}
await Task.WhenAll(concurrentDeleteTasks.Take(3));
```

You also can foreach the collection and set `ttl=10`, these data will be deleted 10s later.

**You can get the latest 5 data：**

```
SELECT f.id, f.lastUpdated FROM yourcosmosdb f ORDER BY f.lastUpdated OFFSET 1 LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks Jason! The problem was with making sure only 5 entries are saved in the first place and not related to retrieving them. I can do a foreach and set ttl, but then it means I need to execute multiple queries against the db. I am thinking of now reading the document from the db, update it in memory to keep only last 5 entries and then write back to the db.